# How to save/retrieve the contents of matlab execution from python for python?

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, file-io

I need to run a matlab script from python. The matlab script returns an array, which I guess could be saved as a *.mat file.

Is it possible to execute the matlab code directly from python, and then retrieve it?

for example:

```
myarr = somematlabbridge.execute("matlab function")
```

Or otherwise, is it possible to do something like this:

```
somematlabbridge.execute("matlab functions to execute the matlab and save it in a file")
```

so that I can then read the file into Python to retrieve the output of the matlab function?

The output that I need from matlab will be a 2D array. By the way, I'm running Python from Anaconda/Spyder.

### Edit

Let me clarify exactly what I'm trying to do.
There's this software [here](http://koen.me/research/selectivesearch/) that I want to execute, which is Matlab. I don't know really know Matlab.
But the script works by simply running `demo.m`. When you run that, then the script creates a bunch of things, including an array called `boxes`. I know this because I can see the code, and because, while in the Matlab environment, I can click on the `boxes` variable in the Workspace and Matlab will show me its contents. Like in this image below:
[image]

This 2D array called `boxes` is what I need to take into my Python script for processing.

So how can this be done?
I don't really know Matlab so I'm not sure if I can say that the demo script is "returning the boxes array", really the last line in the script is only this:

```
boxes = BoxRemoveDuplicates(boxes);
```

So I added this line to Matlab code:

```
return boxes;
```

And then did this in Python:

```
import win32com.client
h = win32com.client.Dispatch('matlab.application')
myboxes= h.Execute ("PATH_TO_FILE\\demo.m")
print myboxes
```

Which gives me

```
??? Error: Unexpected MATLAB operator.
```

What's the correct way to do this?

Comment: what do you get, if you execute print (myarr) ?

Comment: I've no time for a full answer right now, but you can call MATLAB from the command prompt (see: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/102082-how-do-i-call-matlab-from-the-dos-prompt about half way down the answer) so I expect you can use `subprocess` to call MATLAB directly: http://stackoverflow.com/q/89228/2449192 You can have your MATLAB script write to a text file or some such that you can read in with `numpy` (or other file IO routines)

Comment: @Furtano ideally I should just get a 2D array printed out.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that `return boxes` is invalid syntax in MATLAB.

If you want the demo function to return `boxes`, you would need to make sure the first line of the functi0n looks like this:

```
function boxes = demo(yourInputArguments)
```

Not sure how to call it from python.

If things don't work out, you can also try to write the output of the matlab function to a text file, which you can than load in from any program. For that add the following line at the bottom of the file:

```
dlmwrite('boxes.txt',boxes)
```

Or, if you just want to see the result, consider adding only this word to the end of the function, basically a command to print the content of boxes to stdout:

```
boxes
```